# Join multiple tables subquery

Tags: mysql, join

I'm creating logins for a website; on that website users are divided in regions (table names) 55_USERS, 78_USERS etc. So there are 6 tables like that. Do you know the best way how to join them? I'm not so good in writing queries...
Columns that I need from tables is id_client, password, id_region.

Comment: Very conceptional question. The id is primary key. So it could be outer join via 6 tables.

Comment: Seems as if you are looking for `UNION`, not subquery. Also: why do you explicitly partition by table name instead of using MySQL partitioned table feature?

Comment: Better change your table design and put them in a single table.

Comment: I know that is not the best way, but client has database like that,and now i need to find the way to check all of them when someone login...

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, I would also recommend using a [union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) for this. It will allow you to take results from each table and put them all together into one result set. In your case, it would look something like this:

```
SELECT id_client, password, id_region FROM firstUsersTable
UNION
SELECT id_client, password, id_region FROM secondUsersTable
UNION
SELECT id_client, password, id_region FROM thirdUsersTable
UNION
SELECT id_client, password, id_region FROM fourthUsersTable
UNION
SELECT id_client, password, id_region FROM fifthUsersTable
UNION
SELECT id_client, password, id_region FROM sixthUsersTable
```

Answer (score -1):

Create  Region table and remove and rebuild user tables. It will be more painfull.